# Cannot add connection. using vb.net to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while stablishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or wad not accessible. Verify that the instance name is corrrect and that the SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (Provider: name pipes provider error 40 - could not open a connection to SQL Server).

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How can fix this problem?